# Why does this evaluate as false?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does comparing an explicitly called `String` constructor to an implicit string evaluate `true`, but adding the `new` keyword makes it evaluate `false` on deep equals, but `true` again on shallow equals?

```
> "hello"===String("hello")
true
> "hello"==new String("hello")
true
> "hello"===new String("hello")
false
```

**Edit:** after further testing, this appears to happen with all types that have implicit constructors.

**Edit 2:** to clarify, this is not a question of `==` vs. `===`, but one of implicit vs. explicit constructors.

Comment: `typeof "hello"` → `'string'`, `typeof new String("hello")` → `'object'`

Comment: `==` checks just for the value (`"4" == 4 > true`) but `===` checks for the type as well. (`"4" === 4 > false`) since one is a string and the other is a number.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: They both check the type. The `==` enters a type coercion algorithm if it finds that the types are not the same. If `==`only checked the value, then `4 == "4"` would be `false`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `new` keyword you are creating an object. If you were to check the typeof `new String('hello')` you will see that it is of type `object`. Checking the type of `'hello'` on its own will yield `string`.

As you may know, using a strict equals operator (`===`) will check for both value and type, so it will return false due to the types not matching.

The reason the expression without the `new` keyword returns true is because calling upon the `String` global object is [not the same as calling the constructor using `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without using the new keyword) are primitive strings.

As such, the type of the return value will be `string` and not `object`, so the strict check will return true.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `==` and `===` is that `===` requires the type to be the same, while `==` does not.

So this is telling you that both `"hello"` and `String("hello")` are of the same type (which is `string`); but `new String("hello")`, while it has the same value, is a different type (which is `object`)